# How to detect if cherrypy is shutting down

Tags: python, cherrypy

I've made a server based on cherrypy but I have a repetitive task which takes a long time (more than a minute) to run. This is all fine until I need to shut down the server, then I am waiting forever for the threads to finish.

I was wondering how you'd detect a cherrypy shutdown inside the client thread so that the thread could abort when the server is shutting down.

I'm after something like this:

```
class RootServer:
    @cherrypy.expose

    def index(self, **keywords):
        for i in range(0,1000):
            lengthyprocess(i)
            if server_is_shutting_down():
                return
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inspect the state directly:

```
if cherrypy.engine.state != cherrypy.engine.states.STARTED:
    return
```

Or, you can register a listener on the 'stop' channel:

```
class RootServer:

    def __init__(self):
        cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start', self.start)
        cherrypy.engine.subscribe('stop', self.stop)

    def start(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, **keywords):
        for i in range(0,1000):
            lengthyprocess(i)
            if not self.running:
                return
```

The latter is especially helpful if you also want to have the lengthyprocess start (or perform some preparation) when the server starts up, rather than upon a request.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response. The 2nd technique doesn't quite work because self.stop isn't called until after the thread has stopped and the thread won't stop until self.stop is called. Bit of a deadlock, but the 1st technique works a treat.